# Reference a relationship with multiple Foreign Keys in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table Project in a relation One-To-Many with the Site entity.

```
class Project(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    
    id_project = Column ('ID_PROJECT', String (100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    id_conn = Column ('ID_CONN', String (100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    region = Column ('region', String (100), nullable=True)   

    offices = relationship ('Office', backref='project', lazy='subquery')
```

```
class Office(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'office'
    
    id_office= Column ('ID_OFFICE', String (100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    id_project = Column ('ID_PROJECT', String (100), ForeignKey('project.ID_PROJECT'), nullable=False)
    id_conn = Column ('ID_CONN', String (100), ForeignKey('project.ID_CONN'), nullable=False)
    description = Column ('DESCRIPTION', String (1000), nullable=True)
    address = Column ('ADDRESS', String (100), nullable=True)
    note = Column ('NOTE', String (2000), nullable=True)
```

I would like to use 'id_project' and 'id_conn' as ForeignKey to the differents primary key in Project table as showed in the model, but it keeps get this error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Project.offices - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I tried to use only one ForeignKey and it works, but i have a composite key in Project table and i need to keep track of it in possible join.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with this configuration:

```
class Project(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id_project = Column ('ID_PROJECT', String (100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    id_conn = Column ('ID_CONN', String (100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    region = Column ('region', String (100), nullable=True)   

    office = relationship('Office', back_populates='project', lazy='subquery'
```

and

```
class Office(Model):
   __tablename__ = 'office'

    id_office= Column ('ID_OFFICE', String (100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    id_project = Column ('ID_PROJECT', String (100), nullable=False)
    id_conn = Column ('ID_CONN', String (100), nullable=False)
    description = Column ('DESCRIPTION', String (1000), nullable=True)
    address = Column ('ADDRESS', String (100), nullable=True)
    note = Column ('NOTE', String (2000), nullable=True)

    ForeignKeyConstraint([id_project , id_conn ], [Project.id_project , Project.id_conn])

    project = relationship('Project', back_populates='office', foreign_keys="[Office.id_project , Office.id_conn ]", lazy='subquery')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).